# Automatically Enter Answer on InputBox

Tags: vba, excel

Hi How would I run a macro on excel that automatically inserts and "enters" the answer on the inputbox on AutoCad without having to manually do it myself. How would I have to modify my code below:

```
Sub DWG ()
Pump: ans = InputBox("1 = STD Piping" & vbCrLf & _
           "2 = Omit Pump" & vbCrLf & _
           "3 = SBPP", "Pump Piping")

Select Case ans

Case "1":
: Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("PUMP_PIPING_" & Size)
            layerObj.LayerOn = True
Case "2":

: Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("OMIT_PUMP_" & Size)
            layerObj.LayerOn = True
Case "3":

: Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("STBP_" & Size)
            layerObj.LayerOn = True


Case Else: MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.", vbCritical, MSG: Exit Sub

End Select
```

Comment: Why do you open an input box if you don't want user intervention?

Comment: I started off using the inputBox but now I want to create a gooey so that the user can just enter the different options the press a "go" button and the command is generated. So now it's quite difficult for me to go about that because there is just too many codes which are linked to InputBoxes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "enter" a Inputbox automatically in an easy way - and even if it would be possible I think you shouldn't - your code will get a nightmare.

You could pass the "made" choice as an optional parameter to your routine and show the InputBox only if the parameter was omitted:

```
Sub DWG(Optional answer As String = "")

    If answer = "" Then
       answer = InputBox("1 = STD Piping" & vbCrLf & _
           "2 = Omit Pump" & vbCrLf & _
           "3 = SBPP", "Pump Piping")
    End If
    select case answer
        ....
end sub
```

However that will not save you from going thru all your code.